# FileNotFoundException for local WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, glassfish

I try to implement a consumer for my jax-ws @Stateless @WebService bean webservice. The service runs fine and I can successfully test it using NetBeans's/GlassFish's webservice testing functionality.

The consumer is a Servlet deployed with the same ear as the service. I inject the service using

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/EchoService/EchoBean?wsdl")
EchoService echo;
```

but whenever I open the servlet all I get is a stack trace with the following root exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://localhost:8080/EchoService/EchoBean/__container$publishing$subctx/null?WSDL
```

I can load the WSDL from `http://localhost:8080/EchoService/EchoBean/?WSDL` in the browser but I have no clue about the `__container$publishing$subctx/null` part, which is not mentioned anywhere in my code.

The full stack trace is available at http://pastebin.com/dneCPj8z

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Glassfish 4, `@WebServiceRef` annotation does not work properly on servlets and filters. This is filed under GLASSFISH-20740. Check [this thread](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20740).

HTH

Comment: Given that this was reported in September 2013 my use case does not seem to be very common.

Comment: @jmaschad Exactly. Most people use external clients or session beans for this purpose. Additionally, Oracle recently abandoned commercial support for Glassfish so reported bugs are now resolved much slower, if resolved at all. Very bad decision from the Java community perspective, because Glassfish was an excellent open-source application server and now it would only serve as a reference implementation for Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, under:

`"Your project name"/Configuration Files/xml-resources/web-service-references/"Your web service name"/wsdl/`

copy the "localhost_8080" folder and paste it under:

`"Your project name"/Web pages/WEB-INF/wsdl.`

also change:

`@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/EchoService/EchoBean.wsdl")`

to:

`@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/EchoService/EchoBean.wsdl")`